# What is meant by "effectively tail recursive"?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Chapter 7 in FP in Scala deals with creating a purely functional library for handling concurrency. To that end, it defines a type

```
type Par[A] = ExecutorService => Future[A]
```

and a set of useful functions such as fork

```
def fork[A] (a: => Par[A]): Par[A] = 
 es => es.submit(new Callable[A] {
  def call = a(es).get
 })
```

One of the exercises is about the function sequence with the following signature

```
def sequence[A](ps: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]]
```

The solution using foldRight is straightforward. However the authors included two other versions as answers, one of which states the following

```
// This implementation forks the recursive step off to a new logical thread,
// making it effectively tail-recursive. However, we are constructing
// a right-nested parallel program, and we can get better performance by 
// dividing the list in half, and running both halves in parallel. 
// See `sequenceBalanced` below.
def sequenceRight[A](as: List[Par[A]]): Par[List[A]] = 
  as match {
    case Nil => unit(Nil)
    case h :: t => map2(h, fork(sequenceRight(t)))(_ :: _)
  }
```

I am not quite sure what is meant by "effectively tail recursive". From the definition of fork it is clear that it accepts a by name parameter and so *map2(h, fork(sequenceRight(t)))(_ :: _)* will not evaluate the second parameter (until the executor service is provided). But that doesn't tell me how and why it is "effectively tail recursive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take some `List(a, b, c)`. After passing it into `sequenceRight` it will turn into:

```
map2(
  a,
  fork(
    map2(
      b,
      fork(
        map2(
          c,
          fork(unit(Nil)
        )(_ :: _)
      )
    )(_ :: _)
  )
)(_ :: _)
```

This isn't tail recursive at all and compiler cannot treat it as one. However, when you would evaluate how it would be executed:

- `fork` would make whatever you pass to it async, so it would return immediately,
- `map2` implementation will not block the execution until `fork` is executed to apply the function passed to `map2`, instead it would asynchronously transform the result calculated in `fork` to prepend the value
- since recursion is done asynchronously, posting things to ExecutorService and appending operation to `Future` let you treat ExecutorService+Future like a trampoline

As a result what actually happens is:

- `sequenceRight(List(a, b, c))` call `map2(a, fork(sequenceRight(List(b, c))(_ :: _)

  - `a` will complete when it will complete but we can hold it as value even now
  - `fork(sequenceRight(List(b, c))` is scheduled, but we aren't waiting until it complete, we can pass it around already
  - we can create a `Future` that will combine the result of the 2 above (and return it) without waiting for any of them completing!
- as a result, this `Future` is returned immediately! It still runs, but this one call is finished!
- same is true for recursively created `Future`s
- once `c` and `fork(unit(Nil))` completes, `rResult :: Nil` is computed
- this allows completion of `bResult :: cResult :: Nil`
- and this finally allows computation of the final result

In other words tail-recursive refers to recursive calls being rewritten into `while` loop to avoid stack overflow. But stack overflow is only an issue if recursive calls are being made synchronously. If you are returning something async, then the backtracing is shoved to ExecutionServices and Futures' observers, so they are hidden in a heap. From that point of view they solve the same issue of stack-overflow as tail-recursive calls, so "in spirit" they could be considered somewhat similar.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. it was very helpful! as you pointed out in the last paragraph, the key point here is whether the stack is allocated in the current thread or in other threads allocated by executor service(since each thread will get its own stack provided by the jvm). Since fork ensures that it is the latter, to the thread that calls map2 doesn't bear the burden of allocating stack frames to store intermediate results and thus for the calling thread it becomes "effectively tail recursive".

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly *not* tail-recursion, and I think, they know it – that's why they added "effectively" :).

What they must mean is that this implementation does not create additional frames on stack for recursive invocations, which is true, since those invocations happen asynchronously, as you noted.

Now, whether this situation is even deserves to be called a "recursion" at all  is a good question. I don't think there is a single accepted answer to that. I personally lean toward "yes", because the definition of recursion as "referencing itself" definitely includes this situation, and I don't really know how else to define it so that async invocations are excluded, but tail-recursion is not.

BTW, I am not much of an expert in Javascript, but I hear that the term "asynchronous recursion" is used fairly widely there.